# A Very Specific ActiveRecord Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-models

I'm will try to explain my dilemma as best I can.

I have a 2 models 
**Users** and **Devices**

Devices has a type column. For example it can be a Tablet or a Smart Phone.

I then have another model **Ownership**

This model belongs to both Users and Devices so it will have entries in the table matching users to devices representing that that user owns that device.

I need to setup some validations on the **Ownership** model the primary ones begin.

- No device can have more than one ownership entry (simple as validating that device_id column is unique)
- A user can only have ownership of one device for each type of device available.

So how would I make a validation for this last part? I can't set the client_id table to unique because they will have multiple entries for different types of devices. But I want them to only have one row per type of device.

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if you need more details. I would appreciate any insight!

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like you want validates uniqueness with a scope option.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: That's what I was looking at earlier. But can that scope options be on a column in my Devices table?              So I would have something like validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :device_type??,
    message: "Can only own one device type." }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :device_id, uniqueness: true
validate :device_type_unique?

def device_type_unique?
  if Ownership.includes(:device).where('devices.type = ? AND ownerships.user_id = ?', self.device.type, self.user_id)
    errors.add(:user_id, "Can only own one device type.")
  end
end
```